# Can I access the parent view's Model from a child partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Can I access the parent view's Model from a child partial view? I get conflicting information when I look this up.

If so, can anyone point me at an example?

And if so, would it help to make the child model object a property of the parent model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.If you are talking about strongly binding the views with ViewModels then you can only access the model which you pass to your partial view.But if you want something to be available in partial view or any other view you can use ViewData dictionary.

Other thing you can always do and should do is to make your view model in such a way so that it caters to your parent view as well as your all child views .So to answer your last question yes you can make child model object a property of your parent model.

Another point here is that make sure you keep your domain model separate from View model which you are going to bind to Views and not make UI related changes to your domain model for just the sake of binding it to view.

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to ask is using ViewData/ViewBag the way to do it because they definitely share that. I'm following a very compositional design - making a parent view model whose properties are other independent models that have their own partial views. The underlying models come from a separate independent data layer and are as they need to be for that purpose.

Comment: Thats good... try to avoid view data / bag as much as possible.Doing stuff through your model will make code  more structured and maintainable